# how to assign id's to cloned elements

Tags: php, jquery, database

I want to add id to cloned img tag as I want to store the data of cloned object to database. can anyone help please..I also want to store the x and y positions provide by the user using javascript..I just want to know how to assign different id's to the cloned img tag.
Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
       google.load("jquery", "1.6.3");
       google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.16");
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="dragndrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="include/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="include/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="include/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .col{
float:left;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

 #col1{
width:200px;
height:500px;
border:1px solid black;

}

.drag{
width:100px;
border:1px solid black;
height:40px;
position:relative;
background-color:red;
background-image:url(restaurant/8793_532242100147879_270911928_n.jpg);
}

#droppable{
width:500px;
height :500px;
border:1px solid black;
}

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class = "col" id="col1">
            <img src="" id="drag1" class="drag">                
        </div>
        <div class="col" id ="droppable">

        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

here is dragndrop.js file.
// JavaScript Document

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

   var x = null;

//Make element draggable
$(".drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'fit'
});

$("#droppable").droppable({

    drop: function(e, ui) {

        x = ui.helper.clone();
              x.draggable({
            helper: 'original',
            containment: '#droppable',
            tolerance: 'fit'
        });
        x.appendTo('#droppable');
        ui.helper.remove();
    }
});

});
```